# Find record _id in Mongo through Node.js/Express not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am passing the data to be updated through a form in Angular. The data passes fine but nothing is updated. The record shows as:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("6087b5842abc6fe6ab21d166"), "name" : "Chester", "status" : "Preparing" }
```

I want to be able to update the status as "shipped".

```
// update order status
let updateStatus = (req, res) => {
  let oid = req.body.oid;
  console.log(oid);
  let orderStatus = req.body.orderStatus;
  OrderModel.updateOne({ _id: oid }, { $set: { status: orderStatus } })
    .then((obj) => {
      console.log(obj);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
};
```

Comment: What does this print: `console.log(oid);`. Is there a document in the collection with that id value?

Comment: I used it to print the id from the form. Just to make sure that I am getting data.

Comment: yes the oid passed is the objectId from the item in the collection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure it out! It was since we had mongo generate the ID we had to make sure to use objectId and also someone on my team changed the collection name in the schema..

Here is my solution for anyone who has this issue.

```
 const ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectId;

// update order status
let updateStatus = (req, res) => {
  let oid = req.body.oid;
  let objOid = new ObjectId(oid);
  console.log('objeOid ' + objOid);
  let orderStatus = req.body.orderStatus;
  OrderModel.updateOne(
    { _id: new ObjectId(oid) },
    { $set: { status: orderStatus } }
  )
    .then((obj) => {
      console.log(obj);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
};
```